# Definite integrals without a function

Tags: calculus

Let

the integral from $0$ to $2$ of $f(x) = 13$

the integral from $0$ to $3$ of $f(x) = -10$

the integral from $0$ to $2$ of $g(x) = 8$

the integral from $2$ to $3$ of $g(x) = 14$

Use these values to evaluate the following definite integrals

a) integral from $0$ to $2$ of $(f(x) + g(x))dx =$

b) integral from $0$ to $3$ of $(f(x) - g(x))dx =$

c) integral from $2$ to $3$ of $(3f(x) + 2g(x))dx =$

I have solved the first one but I am having trouble determining what the integral from $0$ to $3$ is of $g(x)$ I have tried multiplying and adding. But I am very confused

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) will make for more legible equations, e.g. $\int_0^2f(x)dx=13$ (`\int_0^2f(x)dx=13`). As for your question,$$\int_0^3gdx=\int_0^2gdx+\int_2^3gdx$$(can you see why?)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a) we know that the integral $\int^{2}_{0} f(x) dx = 13$, and that $\int^{2}_{0} g(x) dx = 8$.

Since we want to find $\int^{2}_{0} f(x) + g(x) dx$, we can split this up into

$\int^{2}_{0} f(x) dx + \int^{2}_{0} g(x) dx$

which in this case is $13 + 8$ or $21$

For b) we know that the integral $\int^{3}_{0} f(x) dx= -10$ and that the integral $\int^{3}_{2} g(x) dx = 14$.

Since we want to find $\int^{3}_{0} f(x) - g(x) dx$ we split this up into

$\int^{3}_{0} f(x) dx- \int^{3}_{0} g(x) dx$.

We know $\int^{3}_{0} f(x) dx$. and we can find $\int^{3}_{0} g(x) dx$ using the property

$\int^{3}_{0} g(x) dx = \int^{2}_{0} g(x) dx + \int^{3}_{2} g(x) dx$

which in our case means $\int^{3}_{0} g(x) dx = 8 + 14$ or $22$

So plugging this back into $\int^{3}_{0} f(x) - g(x) dx$ we have $\int^{3}_{0} f(x) - \int^{3}_{0} g(x) = -10 - 22$ or $-32$

For c) we want to find the integral $\int^{3}_{2} 3f(x) + 2g(x) dx$ which we can split up into

$\int^{3}_{2} 3f(x)dx + \int^{3}_{2} 2g(x)dx$ or $3\int^{3}_{2} f(x) dx+ 2\int^{3}_{2} g(x)dx$

We already know $\int^{3}_{2} g(x)dx$, so all we have to find is $\int^{3}_{2} f(x) dx$, which we can represent as $\int^{3}_{0} f(x) - \int^{2}_{0} f(x)$, or in this case $-10-13$ or $ -23$. Using this we have

$3\int^{3}_{2} f(x) dx+ 2 \int^{3}_{2} g(x) dx = 3(-23) + 2(14) = -69 + 28 = -41$